# why we can reduce the case to positve number?

Tags: real-analysis

This is a equation from Stein-Sharkarchi Real Analysis.

Let $F$ be absolutely continuous and increasing on $[a,b]$ with $F(a)=A$ and $F(b)=B$. Suppose $f$ is any measurable function on $[A,B]$.

Show that $f(F(x))F'(x)$ is measurable on $[a,b]$.
The following is idea:
By the definition of measurable functions, we only need to show that the set $G_a \equiv \{ x | f(F(x))F′(x) > a \}$ is measurable for any $a$.
For $a>0$,
I know $$G_a = \bigcup_{q\in \mathbb{Q}^+}^\infty \big\{ x | f(F(x)) > \frac{a}{q} \big\} \cap \big\{ x| F′(x) > q \big\}$$ and I have shown that it is measurable. Next, I use $G_0=\bigcup_{q=1}^\infty G_{1/n}$ to get it is measurable.

However,this is a problem. I cannot think out any method to prove that the case for $a<0$, I think it is from the complement (or not?). Can someone help me? thanks in advanced.